# Unable to WhiteList emails of Exchange Account using EWS API[ SOAP Request]

Tags: java, soap, exchangewebservices

> We have Developed an application in JAVA which whitelist the emails in Junk
>   Email Folder in Exchange Office 365 account. It is/was working fine in
>   One mailbox where we got the proper response as well. But it's not
>   working in the Production Mailbox, earlier it was working fine.

Working Mailbox SOAP Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Header><h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="20" MajorBuildNumber="1339" MinorBuildNumber="26" Version="V2018_01_08" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/></s:Header><s:Body><m:MarkAsJunkResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"><m:ResponseMessages><m:MarkAsJunkResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success"><m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>



 <m:MovedItemId Id="AQMkADc4ZGExOWRmMC1hGTEg/QAAAA==" ChangeKey="CQAAABYAAADH7Bc"/>


</m:MarkAsJunkResponseMessage></m:ResponseMessages></m:MarkAsJunkResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

Issue Mailbox SOAP Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Header><h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="20" MajorBuildNumber="1339" MinorBuildNumber="26" Version="V2018_01_08" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/></s:Header><s:Body><m:MarkAsJunkResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"><m:ResponseMessages><m:MarkAsJunkResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success"><m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode></m:MarkAsJunkResponseMessage></m:ResponseMessages></m:MarkAsJunkResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

> It Just says, "Success", but it is not moving to Inbox folder.
>
> Please help me out to understand and looking for a positive solution.
>
> Note: changekey in this snippet have been shortened to preserve
>   readability

**New Findings**
I am not able to trace the request/response using fiddler. it shows only the network traffic details, May be I'm doing wrong. I just played around the developer tools in chrome and found the below..
**When I select Not a Junk and opt "Don't Report"**, it shows the below

```
{
   "__type":"MarkAsJunkJsonRequest:#Exchange",
   "Header":{
      "__type":"JsonRequestHeaders:#Exchange",
      "RequestServerVersion":"Exchange2013",
      "TimeZoneContext":{
         "__type":"TimeZoneContext:#Exchange",
         "TimeZoneDefinition":{
            "__type":"TimeZoneDefinitionType:#Exchange",
            "Id":"West Asia Standard Time"
         }
      }
   },
   "Body":{
      "__type":"MarkAsJunkRequest:#Exchange",
      "ItemIds":[
         {
            "__type":"ItemId:#Exchange",
            "Id":"AAMkADk0ZTZmYzk0LWI1NTYtNDhiMi1hNWY1LTVkNjEwYjI5MGJjOQBGAAAAAABJb9uPcu8zT6LnpCUq3LWvBwC46WWBQWmKS69lWTrD0xv/AAABhxDBAAC46WWBQWmKS69lWTrD0xv/AAFjP1QMAAA=",
            "ChangeKey":"CQAAABYAAAC46WWBQWmKS69lWTrD0xv/AAFlA1rA"
         }
      ],
      "IsJunk":false,
      "MoveItem":true,
      "SendCopy":false,
      "JunkMessageHeader":"Outlook junk mail report",
      "JunkMessageBody":"This message was automatically generated by the Junk Mail Reporting Tool in Outlook. The attachment and information below will help Microsoft to improve the quality of its junk mail filters in the future."
   }
}
```

**Note:** Tried by sending "SendCopy":true and it's still the same

**When I select Not a Junk and opt "Report"**, it shows the below **ReportMessageToSafetyLibraryRequest**

```
{
   "__type":"ReportMessageToSafetyLibraryRequest:#Exchange",
   "ItemIds":[
      {
         "__type":"ItemId:#Exchange",
         "ChangeKey":"CQAAABYAAAC46WWBQWmKS69lWTrD0xv/AAFlA1Ks",
         "Id":"AAMkADk0ZTZmYzk0LWI1NTYtNDhiMi1hNWY1LTVkNjEwYjI5MGJjOQBGAAAAAABJb9uPcu8zT6LnpCUq3LWvBwC46WWBQWmKS69lWTrD0xv/AAABhxDBAAC46WWBQWmKS69lWTrD0xv/AAFjP1QLAAA="
      }
   ],
   "ReportAction":2,
   "ActionData":null
}
```

I don't think we have option to handle **ReportMessageToSafetyLibrary** in SOAP Request.

Comment: What security context in the code running under ? not getting an Id back after a move sounds like its moved between mailboxes so maybe its been moved to callers Mailbox if its not being called with the owners creds.

Comment: @GlenScales What does it mean by security context here?.. And I'm just getting a  connection of a single mailbox and invoking the whitelist operation through SOAP request. I'm not passing any other mailbox credentials here. Just wanted to understand how exchange account is rejecting the move here

Comment: Are you using the credentials of the owner of the Mailbox ? or an account that has been granted Full Access to the TargetMailbox ?

Comment: I am using the credentials of the owner of the mailbox only !

Comment: It would be worth trying to do the same thing in OWA, OWA uses the same EWS operation so you can capture the request and result using something like fiddler. I can't reproduce the issue myself

Comment: Do we have OWA API for java ?

Comment: No I mean just logon to OWA in a browser and use the junk button, OWA uses EWS as the underlying API so if you look at what its doing using something like fiddler you will see the underlying request and responses

Comment: @GlenScales Please look in to my New Findings. I have tried fiddler with no luck